# How to access the ext_conf_template.txt (extension configuration) in typoscript?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase

There are a few settings in the `ext_conf_template.txt` in my extension.

I want to check the value of one of these settings, but in `typoscript`, not in PHP.

In PHP it works like this:

```
unserialize($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['myExt'])
```

How should I do this in typoscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar in my code snippet extension (see complete [code on Github](https://github.com/ervaude/fs_code_snippet)), where I just added a custom TypoScript condition:

```
[DanielGoerz\FsCodeSnippet\Configuration\TypoScript\ConditionMatching\AllLanguagesCondition]
  // some conditional TS
[global]
```

The condition implementation is quite simple:

```
namespace DanielGoerz\FsCodeSnippet\Configuration\TypoScript\ConditionMatching;
use DanielGoerz\FsCodeSnippet\Utility\FsCodeSnippetConfigurationUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Configuration\TypoScript\ConditionMatching\AbstractCondition;

class AllLanguagesCondition extends AbstractCondition
{
    /**
     * Check whether allLanguages is enabled
     * @param array $conditionParameters
     * @return bool
     */
    public function matchCondition(array $conditionParameters)
    {
        return FsCodeSnippetConfigurationUtility::isAllLanguagesEnabled();
    }
}
```

And the check for the actual `TYPO3_CONF_VARS` value is done in `FsCodeSnippetConfigurationUtility`:

```
namespace DanielGoerz\FsCodeSnippet\Utility;    
class FsCodeSnippetConfigurationUtility
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    private static function getExtensionConfiguration()
    {
        return unserialize($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['fs_code_snippet']);
    }
    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function isAllLanguagesEnabled()
    {
        $conf = self::getExtensionConfiguration();
        return !empty($conf['enableAllLanguages']);
    }

}
```

Maybe that fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Having to create an extension seems to be a lot for a simple check of a typoscript-setting.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the answer of Marcus I was able to get a extension configuration setting into typoscript. First create the extension setting in `ext_conf_template.txt`:

```
# cat=Storage; type=string; label=storageFolderPid
storageFolderPid = 1
```

In `ext_localconf.php` add the following lines:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTypoScriptConstants(
    "plugin.tx_extensionname.settings.storageFolderPid = ".$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTENSIONS']['extension']['storageFolderPid']
);
```

Then you can use this variabele in your typosript, for instance to create a submenu of a storage folder:

```
lib.submenu = CONTENT
lib.submenu {
    table = tx_extension_domain_model_article
    select {
        pidInList = {$plugin.tx_extensionname.settings.storageFolderPid}
        selectFields = tx_extensionname_domain_model_article.*
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed, though the file is named ext_localconf.php (one underscore).

Answer (score 2):

Handle the configuration via Extension Manager and call  `ExtensionManagementUtility::addTypoScriptConstants()` in your `ext_localconf.php` to set a TypoScript constant at runtime.

This way the value can be set at one location and is available both in lowlevel PHP and TypoScript setup.